# Seeking dataset containing clutter layer of Mumbai

Tags: data-request, india

Where can I find the complete clutter data of Mumbai?

The clutter should contain information related to buildings,roads and water bodies.

Comment: is clutter what I think it is? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clutter